# Seattle Cities Strapline Has The First Letter Of Every Word In Capitals

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

In [Careers Cities](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cities), each city has a strapline visible within the main city image e.g.

[Paris](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cities/paris?f=e)

> Known for its beauty, Paris is home to an exciting tech scene with momentum

[LA](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cities/los-angeles?f=e)

> Life’s a beach in Hollywood’s hotbed of tech

[London](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cities/london?f=e)

> Broaden your worldview in London’s exploding digital sector

etc.

This is [Seattle's](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cities/seattle?f=e)

> Small Startups and Tech Monoliths Offer the Best of Both Worlds

**Why Does It Have To Have Every Word Written With The Initial Letter Capitalised?**

Also [Denver's](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cities/denver?f=e) strapline mysteriously ends in a full stop. Not sure about its capitalisation but at least it's less egregious than Seattle's

> Elevate your tech career in the Mile High city.

Comment: It's there for quite a while, according to [Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackEmployers/status/536999953709957121/photo/1). Anyhow, I guess there are several employees writing those lines, each and his/her own style of writing. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Inconsistency Has Been Corrected.

Thanks for your report!